# seem to be allergic to unfinished wood in the drawers of my new bedroom set

Tags: finishing, toxicity

The smell of wood is causing my throat and nose to swell when I lay down at night, I had to move to another room.

How can I eliminate this odor, or at least mellow I out?

Comment: Do you know what the wood is? Is there any plywood or particleboard/chipboard used in the construction? This isn't necessarily relevant to a successful solution for you, but if there's not a lot of solid wood and more plywood for example it's possible it's not one or more wood species you're reacting to but offgassing from the adhesives used in the manmade board (commonly this would be formaldehyde). There is also a chance it's VOCs from the finish used if it wasn't thoroughly cured when you got the pieces, although this seems less likely.

Comment: Regardless of what the various components are made from 'sealing' the unfinished surfaces of the wood with some finish may be enough here. I'd think you'd need to seal every available surface, including the undersides and backs *of every piece* for this to stand the best chance of working. But, there's no guarantee this will do enough to alleviate your symptoms so you take a gamble trying it.

Comment: Have you experienced irritation with other wood products in the past?

Comment: Maybe show us a picture of the solid wood, if it is solid wood. But definitely needs more detail.

Comment: Am I the only one irked by people that don't add requested information? User hasn't logged in since the day of the question. Will vote to close in a few days.

Comment: This SE does seem to get more abandoned single-line questions; or it feels that way, at least. The problem (and I'm directing this at the OP) is that such questions will never attract good answers. Any good answer will have to start by listing the assumptions and then choosing one or more paths based on one or some of those assumptions. This makes for long essay answers (or short ones that can never _really_ be on-target) where one is not warranted and ain't nobody got time for that.

Comment: Maybe you should go to a doctor and find out what the problem is .

Answer (score 0):

A water born polyurethane would probably work good to seal the wood, I would think 2 coats. Or maybe shellac.